# Locate displaying old files?

Tags: linux, locate

My `locate` command seems to be digging up files which don't exist (old files which I have renamed).

```
sudo locate bus-node.conf
/etc/init/start-bus-node.conf

sudo mv /etc/init/start-bus-node.conf /etc/init/bus-node.conf
mv: cannot stat '/etc/init/start-bus-node.conf' : No such file of directory
```

**Answer:** Ran `updatedb` command, fixed it

Comment: Keep forgetting I can answer my own questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran updatedb command, fixed it

Comment: Please accept this answer even if it's yours so that the question doesn't remain without an accepted answer. Also remove the answer from your question.

Comment: Ok, I had no idea.